# RabbitMQ delete Queue with no connection

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a problem with RabbitMQ. The point is that when the federation loses connection with the queue, the queue is removed. Why is it removing? Messages keep going but in empty space.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your queue to stay you could either set a [TTL (Time To Live)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) on the queue, or you could use [durable queues](https://www.rabbitmq.com/queues.html#durability).

Durable queues will stay. The TTL sets the amount of time the queue can stay alive without having an active consumer/producer.

Comment: Is it possible to set an infinite time?

Comment: Yes, "infinite" queues are durable queues. It's the same, just a different name.